# Change value of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

i'm trying to change a value of a dictionary.

A pice of it look like

```
nuke_plugins_config = {'python_modules': '/dir/python_modules_v001', 'tools': '-/dir/tools_v001'}
```

Now if a use click a checkbox (QListwidgetitem, with checkbox)

I want to change from `-/dir/` to `/dir/` if it's enabled or disabled.

I tried it this way, witch was clearly wrong.

```
    if item.checkState() == 0:
        print self.nuke_plugins_config
        for key, value in self.nuke_plugins_config.iteritems():     
            if "-" in self.value_status[0]:
                pass
            elif "" in self.value_status[0]:
                value = "-/dir/{0}".format(self.value_status[1])
            print value
    elif item.checkState() == 2:
        print self.nuke_plugins_config
        for key, value in self.nuke_plugins_config.iteritems():     
            if "-" in self.value_status[0]:
                pass
            elif "" in self.value_status[0]:
                value = "/dir/{0}".format(self.value_status[1])
            print value
```

Any suggestions, Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to do this? `self.nuke_plugins_config[key] = "-/dir/{0}".format(self.value_status[1])`

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Now on to next issue!

Comment: would give @kuro a +1 on her (or his) *answer*

Comment: @knitti but i did press the arrow up !?

Comment: its alright. @kuro should add her answer as *answer*  (not comment) then she can collect reputation for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per suggestion of @knitti I am adding this as an answer.

The value in the dictionary can be changed as -

```
self.nuke_plugins_config[key] = "-/dir/{0}".format(self.value_status[1])
```

in `if` statement. And for `elif` statement it would be -

```
self.nuke_plugins_config[key] = "/dir/{0}".format(self.value_status[1])
```